# How can I upload my code into 6502 processor?

Tags: assembly, 6502

It has been a while that i have started learning 6502 assembly but how can I upload my code  After I write it in my PC ?

Comment: Presumably it depends what kind of 6502 board you have.  [edit] that into the question.  (And read the vendor's docs for the board).

Comment: has nothing to do with the 6502 it is all about the board.

Answer (score 4):

The 6502 is a just a processor (i.e. CPU only), not a complete microcontroller (MCU) with RAM, non-volatile ROM, and maybe other peripherals.

https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/MOS_Technology_6502

So, you cannot "upload" a program to a simple CPU. You must create a minimal circuit which includes RAM at least (static RAM would be easier to manage than dynamic).

If you want to make practice with the 6502 assembly, I suggest to dig into a variety of emulators. Here is a list: http://www.6502.org/tools/emu/

Answer (score 0):

I suggest use WinVice, a emulator for the 8-bit computer C64  that uses the 6510. It is a modified form of the very successful 6502